# How to Populate an ObservableCollection through bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

Hello I'm trying to Populate an Observable Collection through selected items of an Autocompletebox.

```
<Telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox Itemssource="{Binding People}" />
```

How should I initiate the Observable Collection to bind with RadAutocompleteBox.
And how should I set up SelectedItems binding method.

```
public class People
{
    public string Person
    { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date
    { get; set; }
}

public ObservableCollection<string> Persons{ get; set; }
```

Comment: More code would definitely add some context to your question.

Comment: Is this WPF or Silverlight?

Comment: This is in WPF. Didn't expect more code needed but okay will add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this to get the `SelectedItems` :

Add this to your viewmodel and edit your XAML.
ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<People> SelectedPeoples { get; set; }
```

Xaml:

```
  <Telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox Itemssource="{Binding People}" 
    SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedPeoples , Mode=TwoWay}" 
    SelectionMode="Multiple" />
```

**After your edit**

I see that you try to bind a class to the `RadAutoCompleteBox` rather than the `ObservableCollection People`, you have to bind the property `Persons` to the `RadAutocompleteBox`. This will bind the `ObservableCollection` to the `RadAutoCompleteBox`.

```
<Telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox Itemssource="{Binding Persons}" />
```

Also, you can edit the declaration of your `ObservableCollection` to

```
public ObservableCollection<People> Persons{ get; set; }
```

and edit the XAML like this:

```
<Telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox Itemssource="{Binding Persons}" DataMemberPath="Person" />
```

Your `RadAutocompleteBox` will now show the string `Person` declared in your `People` class.

Comment: You are definitely right. I was binding to class rather than ObservableCOllections. Now i made those changes and also imputted 
`SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedPeoples , Mode=TwoWay}" 
    SelectionMode="Multiple"` but i get this error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: So the Autocomplete has items currently but when an item is selected it crashes

Comment: You have to initialize the `ObservableCollection` in your constructor: `Persons = new ObservableCollection<People>();`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm looking at your code right, you are binding the items source to the class rather than to the collection. For an item's source binding to the collection is needed. You set the *data context* to the class.

```
Itemssource="{Binding Persons}"
```